# horizontal histogram analysis via OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working on an image processing project in `java` which is based on OpenCV library. I need to calculate the number of white pixels in each row of the image. at the first I thought it will be done via `Imgproc.calcHist` method(calculating it's histogram) but as I read the documentation I figured out that my aim is not reachable via that method. how should I do that? I searched the Net but did not find any thing related to `horizontal histogram analysis via OpenCV`.

Comment: A long-winded way would be to treat each row as a ROI and `calcHist` on it, but much easier to just loop through the pixels and count them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#reduce(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int)) function, to get a horizontal/vertical projection to one row/col.

each value in there is the count of pixels in a row/col